# Does changing the video quality on YouTube impact audio quality?

Tags: audio, video, youtube

Sometimes I'll find a really awesome song on YouTube but it will default to HD video playback which constantly buffers on my slow internet connection. All I care about is the audio quality, not the video quality, so can I lower the video quality to 240p without sacrificing audio quality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally as the video quality, size, and codec is changed, the audio is also different that is used for that video data rate. The audios are often relative in size to the video. 
The amount of data used for the audio ranges from barely usable for music at all, to very nice, and varies depending on the video codec used and (of course) the audio codec.

There are charts on [the Wikipedia page of YouTube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube) which are mostly up to date, you could use that to find a balance.

Can you select a low video resolution, without sacrificing audio?  For the most part: no, they aren't going to make tiny videos with audio data that is larger than the video. It also depends on more than the "resolution" as there are different methods used. Video codecs that are (more often) standardly used with specific audio codecs. Audio codecs that use different compression methods, and "sound good" at different data rates (ex vorbis).

Answer (score 8):

<strike>From [YouTube's *Recommended upload encoding settings (Advanced)*](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en):</strike>

> ### Bitrate
>
> Note that the bitrates below are recommendations for uploads. Audio playback
>   bitrate is **not** related to video resolution.

So it seems audio quality is the same, irrespective of the selected video resolution. However, the audio quality will be as good (or bad) as the original video that was uploaded to YouTube.

Never mind my answer. **@Psychogeek** is right and YouTube does indeed change audio bitrates and codec. I'm not sure if it affects the perceived audio quality though.

You can find out what the current audio/video quality is by using the online [YouTube video info tool](http://www.h3xed.com/blogmedia/youtube-info.php). It'll list all the **`itags`** for a YouTube video in addition to other information like bitrate (divide the listed number by 1000 to get the bitrate in kbps).

To find out the audio and video **`itags`** for the video you're watching, right-click inside the player and select **`Copy debug info`** and paste it into a text editor and search for **`itag`**. Look up the **`itag`** values and compare them to the output of [YouTube video info tool](http://www.h3xed.com/blogmedia/youtube-info.php). You can additionally, [look them up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_formats) as well.

You can play a YouTube video in the lowest resolution setting and see what the audio stream **`itag`** value is. If you find that it's fairly high (i.e. 251 or 141 for [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), meaning 160 kbit/s or 256 kbit/s respectively) you can keep playing it at that quality level without worrying about sacrificing audio quality.

Comment: Did not know about itags! Will definitely have to check it out.

Comment: @terminex9 Neither did I. You learn something interesting everyday :)

Comment: Spectacular answer!